# MongoDB in Meteor missing $max operator

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Meteor seems to be missing the $max update operator.

I'm following the documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/max/#up._S_max) in the meteor mongo shell:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.vesrion()
2.4.9
meteor:PRIMARY> db.scores.insert({ _id: 1, highScore: 800, lowScore: 200 })
meteor:PRIMARY> db.scores.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "highScore" : 800, "lowScore" : 200 }
meteor:PRIMARY> db.scores.update( { _id: 1 }, { $max: { highScore: 950 } } )
Invalid modifier specified $max
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I can simulate the $max behavior by adding $lt clauses to my update condition, but it's clunky and doesn't work well if I also want to update other fields (for example, increment numGamesPlayed by 1 while also updating highScore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing you're doing wrong, the problem is that the `$max` update operator was added in 2.6.

If you click the `2.6 (current)` in the upper left of that doc page and select version 2.4 docs instead you'll see that `$max` is not there.

The best reference I can find is in the [2.6 release notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/#insert-and-update-improvements).

Comment: Ah, I was looking for the "added in version X" comment but couldn't find it. Thanks for pointing that out!

Unfortunately I can't just "upgrade MongoDB" when using Meteor. I'll have to split the update into a few operations.

Comment: @skishore Right, that seems to be missing for some reason.  I added a link to the 2.6 release notes that mentions the new operators.